# Question about a symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, latin-square

Let us have a $2n+1\times 2n+1$ symmetric matrix $A$ where $n$ is a nonnegative integer. We write the numbers $1,2,...,2n+1$ in every row and column, in an arbitrary sequence.

Prove that in the main diagonal, every number from $1,2,...,2n+1$ can be found exactly once.

The task seems kind of "obvious" for me, I tried it for smaller $n$'s and because the matrix is symmetric, this has to be true.

Any idea how to do the solid proving? Thanks :)

Comment: Please clarify your question so that it is clear exactly what kind of matrix you're looking for.

Comment: You need to write $1,2,...2n+1$ in every column and line in an arbitrary sequence, but each number can be found in each line and each column, please tell me what is not understandable, and I edit. :)

Comment: Do you mean to find a size $2n + 1$ [Latin square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square)?

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that this is called so, but yes, than I mean that :)

Comment: It's nice to know that, but the proving is still the question. :) Thanks for linking that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,2n+1\}$ is in exactly $2n+1$ entries.

On the other hand, if there is an $i$ *not* appearing on the main diagonal, then it must appear in an even number of entries since the matrix is symmetric. This would contradict the first fact.

Comment: It is really that simple, thanks! :)

Comment: By the same idea, in a $2n\times 2n$ symmetric Latin square, every $i$ appears on the diagonal an even number of times.

Answer (score 0):

Every number $1\leq i\leq 2n+1$ must appear $2n+1$ times in your matrix (Once in every row.)

Suppose that there is some number $i$ which never appears in the diagonal. Let $p$ be the number of times $i$ appears in the top half of our matrix, and $q$ the number of times $i$ appears in the lower half of our matrix. Since the matrix is symmetric, $p=q$. But since $i$ never appears on the diagonal, then $p+q=2n+1$, i.e $2n+1$ is even, which is a contradiction.

Therefore, every number from $1$ to $2n+1$ appears at least once on the main diagonal. Since there are $2n+1$ spots, then every number appears exactly once on the main diagonal .